# why numpy.ndarray' object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.x

I typed that code,

```
def func1(x1,x2): return lambda x: RHS_func(x)*((x-x1)/(x2-x1))\
def func2(x1,x2): return lambda x: RHS_func(x)*((x1-x)/(x1-x2))
```

it shows
numpy.ndarray object is not callable. Is there any different way to write that function?

Comment: What is `RHS_func`? Are `x1`, `x2` ndarrays?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal verifiable example.